# PropertyNotFoundException for filter in Richfaces datatable

Tags: filter, datatable, richfaces

I am trying to add filtering to a **rich:datatable** but am having problems with the **PropertyNotFoundException** - using an example from the showcase (Richfaces 4) I have the following

```
<f:facet name="noData">
   Nothing found
</f:facet>

<rich:column filter="#{mailerBean.firstNameFilterImpl}">
  <f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText value="First Name" />
<h:inputText value="#{mailerBean.firstNameFilter}" id="input">
  <a4j:ajax event="blur" render="dataTable" execute="@this" />
</h:inputText>
  </f:facet>

  <h:outputText value="#{person.firstName}" />
</rich:column>
```

The Bean contains

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MailerBean  implements Serializable {

............

public String getFirstNameFilter() {
  return firstNameFilter;
}

public void setFirstNameFilter(String firstNameFilter) {
  this.firstNameFilter = firstNameFilter;
}

public Filter<?> getFirstNameFilterImpl() {
  return new Filter<Person>() {
    public boolean accept(Person t) {
        String firstName = getFirstNameFilter();
        if (firstName == null || firstName.length() == 0 ||
            firstName.toLowerCase().contains(t.getFirstName().toLowerCase())) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

The error I get is

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /mailinglistpage.xhtml @66,67
>   filter="#{mailerBean.firstNameFilterImpl}": Property
>   'firstNameFilterImpl' not found on type
>   com.patcomsys.zuzz.mailer.web.MailerBean

The method is in the bean and it does return a Filter object - can you see anything wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Have you rebuilt the project properly? I'm getting this error when I only restart the deployed project without rebuilding it.

Comment: Excellent - many thanks for your help - I normally have the build automatically set on but have cleared it for some reason